# Uniqueness of the explicit solution for a recursive equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Suppose we have a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which is defined by a recursive rule $x_n = g(x_1, x_2, ..., x_{n-1})$.

There are infinitely many explicit functions $f(n)$ which satisfy $f(n) = x_n,\, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Does this ever pose an issue when attempting to solve for $f(n)$? How come when we usually solve recurrence relations we can get "nice" solutions?

Comment: For a given set of initial conditions there is only one function $f$ with domain $\Bbb Z^+$ such that $f(n)=x_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: Ah right, seems obvious in hindsight. Thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome!